# Visual Project Installers Project and Visual Studio Community 2022 Shortcut does not launch application

Tags: c#

[image]I am trying to deploy my application I wrote in C# using Visual Project Installer. The project builds and does not give any error both visible and silent. I also verified that all necessary files were in the application folder. Following the logic I built a shortcut on the desktop folder pointing to the executable and it did not work. I built another shortcut pointing to the Primary Output and it pointed to the DLL and it also did not work as well. I built another shortcut to the Published Items and it did not work. I am using .NET 6.0 Framework. The Program gets installed into the Program Files folder. When I go to the program files in the computer and clicked the exe and it did not run but when I run the exe as administrator it runs.

I am trying to get it to run when I click the shortcut and not navigating to the program files folder and run as admin, and even then it does not run with the current users permissions. I desire to know any details why this is happening and how can I modify my setup to get it running.

In the Visual Project Installers I did not change any permissions or settings that would lead for it be needed to run with administrator privileges. If there is an option in the extension that causes that I would like to know where I could find it because I am unaware if it exists?

I added the File Installation Properties of the exe that I am installing.

Comment: _I desire to know any details why this is happening_: Then you should provide more information. It seems that your program may need administrative privileges to run. What does your program do? How did you create a shortcut? What is the location of the _.exe_.

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid I added more details about the exe and the location is that the exe is in the Program Files folder.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator